# Any “features oriented” project/product planning software out there?

Tags: project-management, planning, product-management

Is there any "features oriented" project/product planning software? By features oriented I refer to a software that will organize all the software features and relations between them. Is there anything like that?

3 features that I would really need is :

1. the ability to design connections between features.
2. I would also like to be able to categories features.
3. tagging features.

Lets say I'm developing a blog, categorizing would be creating a category for the blog control panel/management area and another category would be the front pages of the blog.

As for the connections, lets stick with the blog example, so at the control panel category I'll have a feature called: "comments moderation", and at the front category I would have a feature called "comments system". I would like to be able to make a connection between those two features since they are literally connected.

As for the tagging, let's say I have another feature at the front category called "post likes", and those two features require the user to be logged in, I would like to be able to tag those two features as "require login".

Comment: Welcome aboard. Where do you want this software to run? In the browser? Windows? Linux? Mac? Android? iOs? Other? Must it be free, or do you have a budget. Do you care how you connect things? E.g by drag & drop, or clicking both then clicking connect? Any other features? The more detailed info you give us, the more help we can give you. Good luck, this is an interesting question